# Simple webpage analytics from CLI

Tags: web

I have a website that I put together using a website builder, as opposed to hosting it on a private server.

In simple terms, I'm wondering if there's a way to use terminal to keep an eye on how many people are visiting the website. Doesn't need to be anything fancy, just a simple count of the visitors to the domain.

Comment: That depends on how it is hosted. If you have access to the access logs, you could use something like [goaccess.io], but I can see reasons why your provider might only provide you with statistics they generate for you.

Comment: I use zabbix, but it's too complicated for you. If you use apache, try the goaccess. https://goaccess.io/

Comment: note that unless you expect more than three digits of unique visitors each days, bots will probably dominate your statistics, at least of the publicly available landing page.